# How to split by regex in shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sh, regex-group

I have the following output example:

```
[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK
some text here
[OK] OKO.II
```

and I want to parse it via a this regex `\[OK\](\s+\w+)\.(\w+)\n([^\[]+)`

[image]

but when I am trying to create my shell script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the text to parse
text="[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK
some text here
[OK] OKO.II"

# Create an empty list to hold the group lists
# Loop through the text and extract all matches
regex_pattern="\[OK\](\s+\w+)\.(\w+)\n([^\[]+)"
while [[ $text =~ $regex_pattern ]]; do
  # Create a list to hold the current groups
  echo "Matched_1: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  echo "Matched_2: ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  echo "Matched_3: ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  echo "-------------------"
done
```

Is not going to output anything...

Comment: `bash` is not `Perl` or `PCRE`. `\w` should be replaced by `[a-zA-Z_]` and I doubt `bash` can do multiline regex with `\n`

Comment: The `\n` (you may introduce a literal line break in the pattern) and `\w` (replace with `[[:alnum:]_]`) / `\s` (replace with `[[:space:]]`) are minor issues, you just can't do multiple matching easily the way you did. Also, consider quoting the `$text` variable.

Comment: if I am going to replace those the regex is going to look like this, right?` \[OK\](\[[:space:]]+\[[:alnum:]_]+)\.(\[[:alnum:]_]+)\n([^\[]+)` but if so, I will get an error `grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]`. Also if this is not possible like this... then how can I obtain an multiple matching in bash?

Comment: No way to use multiline in `bash`, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash does not do **global** matching.

But what you can do: if there's a match then remove the *prefix ending in the matched text* from the text string.

```bash
text="[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK
some text here
[OK] OKO.II"

re=$'\[OK\][[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]_]+)\.([[:alnum:]_]+)([^[]*)'
#                  no newline characters in the regex  ^^^^^^^

while [[ $text =~ $re ]]; do
    # output the match info
    declare -p BASH_REMATCH
    # and remove the matched text from the start of the string
    # (don't forget the quotes here!)
    text=${text#*"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"}
done
```

outputs

```
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'[OK] AAA.BBBBBB\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n' [1]="AAA" [2]="BBBBBB" [3]=$'\naaabbbcccdddfffed\nasdadadadadadsada\n')
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]=$'[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK\nsome text here\n' [1]="CCC" [2]="KKKKKKK" [3]=$'\nsome text here\n')
declare -a BASH_REMATCH=([0]="[OK] OKO.II" [1]="OKO" [2]="II" [3]="")
```

Clearly, this destroys the `$text` variable, so make a copy if you need it after the loop.

The regex makes the solution a bit fragile: there cannot be any open brackets in the "following" lines.

---

Having said all that, this is not what bash is really good for. I'd use awk or perl for this task.

Comment: But I am not sure why the regex have to look like this instead of a normal one

Comment: bash uses "POSIX extended" regular expression, not perl-compatible PCRE. bash does not have `\s`, `\w`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `PCRE` with `grep` (as explained in comments, `bash` have no *multiline mode*):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the text to parse
text="[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK
some text here
[OK] OKO.II"

grep -Pzo '(?m)\[OK\](\s+\w+)\.(\w+)\n([^\[]+)' <<< "$text"
```

### Output

```
[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
[OK] CCC.KKKKKKK
some text here
```

Your regex is yours.

Check [regex101 explanations](https://regex101.com/r/2WCk2e/1) about `(?m)`

---

Or with `Perl` (different output):

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print $& if m/\[OK\](\s+\w+)\.(\w+)\n([^\[]+)/' <<< "$text"
```

### Output

```
[OK] AAA.BBBBBB
aaabbbcccdddfffed
asdadadadadadsada
```